# find a path from A to B double array recursion JAVA

Tags: java

im new here. kinda need help with a recursion question
my code needs to find how many steps it takes to get from a specific location user picks to another one.
i got a few function i created before:

legalNeighbor - it checks if 2 numbers are near each other and if they are the same color - if so return true
locationNeighbor - it checks if the neighbor is on top and returns 1 - if under 2 - right side 3 - and left side 4

what i tried to do is take the double array i get from user (map) make another double array of same size (map2) and fill it with -1

and then as i check the neighbors i change the -1 to 0 if its near, then the next place will be 1 and the next 2 and that way at the end of the program i print the place im suppose to get to (i2 j2) and it will print how many steps it took to get there(since i put counter in the current place)

my problem in my code is it cant continue down and once that happens it stops the program, i want to somehow just go 1 step back and continue the code
i believe this is the problematic area

```
if(legalNeighbor(map,i1,j1,i2,j2)==false){
            map2[i1][j1]=-1;
            return 0;
```

this is the code, i think using a throw exception can solve this, but im not sure how to do that (we just learned it today in school)

```
public static int distance(int[][] map, int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2) {
    if (i1==i2&&j1==j2)
        return 0;
    int x=0, mapCheck[][] = new int [map.length][map[0].length];//create a new array in size of map
    for (int k=0; k<map.length; k=k+1) //loop from 0 to map size
        for (int s=0; s<map[0].length; s=s+1) // loop from 0 to map size
            mapCheck[k][s]=-1; // copy map to new array ans
    mapCheck[i1][j1]=0;
    x=distance(map,i1,j1,i2,j2,mapCheck,1);
    return x;
}

public static int distance(int[][] map, int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2, int[][]map2, int counter) {
    if(legalNeighbor(map,i1,j1,i2,j2)==true){ // if its 1 step before the end
        map2[i2][j2]=counter; // put the last number
    }
    print(map2);
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1-1,j1,i1,j1)==1&&map2[i1-1][j1]==-1){ //up
            map2[i1-1][j1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1-1,j1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1+1,j1,i1,j1)==2&&map2[i1+1][j1]==-1){ //down
            map2[i1+1][j1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1+1,j1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1,j1+1,i1,j1)==3&&map2[i1][j1+1]==-1){ //right
            map2[i1][j1+1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1,j1+1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1,j1-1,i1,j1)==4&&map2[i1][j1-1]==-1){ //left
            map2[i1][j1-1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1,j1-1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        if(legalNeighbor(map,i1,j1,i2,j2)==false){
            map2[i1][j1]=-1;
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            int x=map2[i2][j2];
            return x;
        }
}
```

Comment: You say "i want to somehow just go 1 step back and continue the code". You might be looking for backtracking? https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit594-2012/Pages/backtracking.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking (and more on google...)

Comment: your question is not clear. you have a recursion in `distance` function but you don't want to stop but go back 1 step and continue - what does it mean? please clearly state your objective and why do you think the problematic area of your code is problematic?

Comment: in that area where i say it's problematic is because once i do the return 0 it doesn't continue to check the program "left and right" that are under the "down" function area
when i run the code this is what it prints at the end
0-1-1-1-1
1-1-1-1-1
2-1-1-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1

since it checks down, and then it sees there is a 4 so it returns 0 and then stops the program instead of going to the right 

{ {1,1,1,1,1}, 
                 {1,1,1,1,4}, 
                 {1,1,1,1,1}, 
                 {4,4,4,4,1}, 
                 {1,4,4,4,1}};

Comment: it wont left me go down lines in comment, sorry about that

Comment: Is your `int[][] map` argument a weighted graph represented as an adjacency matrix?  If so, then it sounds like you need Dijkstra's algorithm or some variant thereof.  Unless your assignment requires that you use some other recursive approach...